# which api use to post of facebook friend wall from blackberry?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, blackberry, facebook-fql

I am using graph API which is [Facebook Me API](https://github.com/emobtech/Facebook-API-ME) in Blackberry to post on friends wall. But it is clearly listed that posting on friends wall functionality is removed with graph API. [Please check this link for reference](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013).

So,I am not able to post on friend's wall. However i am able to post on my own wall.

As i know there are other two ways it can be possible. Facebook FQL and Facebook Dialog.

So, is there any support for both to post on friend's wall?

Please reply me on same. For more information i want facebooki support for the blackberry 7.0 or more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anyway else to phrase it: **You cannot post to a friend's wall using the API period.** There is no support for it, and it is listed right there in the roadmap.

> We have found that posting content via API (stream.publish) on a friend's wall lead to a high incidence of **user dissatisfaction** (hiding content, blocking the app). After the migration period, posting content to friends' timelines via stream.publish will no longer be allowed. Please use the Feed Dialog for posting.

The feed dialog is a manual user generated action. FQL is not used for posting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why you give me -ve for asking such question. Please let me know if i am wrong in any manner to ask question.